# jquery slideDown and slideUp() not working for partial showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to show and hide partially with jquery sliding functions?

Basically, there's a list with 7 items. But only the 1st two are showing initially, while the rest is hidden. I want that when the user clicks to view more, all 7 items should show. And when he/she clicks again only the 1st two are showing and the rest is hidden again. But I can't manage to do it. Please give me some light, thanks.

jquery:

```
var ul = $('ul'), 
    showMoreLnk = $('a.show-more');

$('a').click(function(e){

  if(ul.outerHeight() === 38){
    ul.find('li.hide').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

    ul.slideDown(function(){
        showMoreLnk.text('Show less');
    });

  } else {
    ul.slideUp(function(){
        showMoreLnk.text('Show more');
        ul.find('li.show').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    });
  }

  e.preventDefault();

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 4</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 5</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 6</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 7</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="show-more">show more</a>
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('ul li.hide').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.
http://sim.plified.com/2008/09/15/sliding-content-from-a-partial-height-with-jquery/

and the example:
http://sim.plified.com/jQuery/slide/#

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
$('a.show-more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hidden_list = $('ul li.hide');

    if (hidden_list.is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).html("show less");
        hidden_list.slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $(this).html("show more");
        hidden_list.slideUp();
    }
 });
```

I also created this for you to test in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Shanison/H4vbB/2/